# How to enable connection pooling in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using `Flask-SqlAlchemy` with a MySQL database. And recently I started getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1040, 'Too many connections')
```

After some digging, it seems that I'm not using the connection pooling.

Based on my research `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` is now deprecated in v2.4 and shouldn't be used anymore.

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
```

So what is the correct way of doing it?

**Config**:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:PASSWORD@localhost/main_db'

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'radius':        'mysql://root:PASSWORD@localhost/radius_db',
    'cache':         'mysql://root:PASSWORD@localhost/cache_db',
}
```

**Code:**

```
def make_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="../templates")
    app.config.from_object(config)
    db.init_app(app)

app = my_fabric.make_app()
```

According to SqlAlchemy, I'm supposed to do this via `create_engine`

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pw@host/db", pool_size=20, max_overflow=0))
```

But Flask-SqlAlchemy is supposed to abstract this out. So I don't know how this should be configured.

**UPDATE:**

I'm running uWSGI with two processes.

I have now increased the max_connections to 500. It's hard to say if I have high traffic, but my database statistics after 16 hours showing this:

```
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name                                         | Value               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Aborted_connects                                      | 5                   |
| Connection_errors_accept                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_internal                            | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_max_connections                     | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                        | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_select                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                             | 0                   |
| Connections                                           | 3897                |
| Locked_connects                                       | 0                   |
| Max_used_connections                                  | 167                 |
| Max_used_connections_time                             | 2019-11-29 00:11:51 |
| Mysqlx_connection_accept_errors                       | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connection_errors                              | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_accepted                           | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_closed                             | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_rejected                           | 0                   |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_longest_seen | 117                 |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost         | 0                   |
| Ssl_client_connects                                   | 0                   |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                              | 0                   |
| Ssl_finished_connects                                 | 0                   |
| Threads_connected                                     | 97                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

AND

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections";
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Connections       | 3896  |
| Threads_cached    | 8     |
| Threads_connected | 97    |
| Threads_created   | 365   |
| Threads_running   | 2     |
+-------------------+-------+
```

AND

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 500   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The default max connections in MySQL seems to be 151, and by default SQLAlchemy uses `QueuePool` (except for SQLite and some other configurations), which – again by default – holds on to 5 connections and has a max overflow limit of 10. Given that you have 3 separate databases setup in the same server, you should have 3 engines and so at tops 45 connections per **process**. Do you use a forking server and have heavy traffic? 4 processes all maxing out their pools would exhaust the default 151 limit. Do you have other services using the same MySQL server?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm also running uWSGI with 2 processes. I have only one server, I have added more details to my questions about the database statistics after 16 hours uptime. I have a nightly job running that is mainly causing the issue. It goes through many rows and needs to delete a number of rows. Maybe that on top of everything else is a problem.  Please see my edit, is 500 max connection excessive? I also have set the `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` to 3600 seconds.

Comment: Could you include `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';`? While an infuriating answer, I guess "Is 500 excessive?" depends on your available hardware. MySQL documentation hints that the default value has been chosen with the common LAM... stack in mind.

Comment: Sure, I've added it.  My hardware is an AWS `t3.small` 2 vCPU and 2 GB RAM.

Answer (score -2):

You can use sessions instead of connections

```
my_session = Session(engine)
results = my_session.execute(query)
my_session.close()
```

and when creating the engine you can set

```
pool_recycle=60.
```

(or a little higher). https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#pool-setting-recycle

Not saying this will solve your issues entirely, but I've rarely encountered problems using this setup.

Comment: I appreciate your response. But I'm using `Flask-Sqlalchemy`. It's interesting to see that you have set the pool_recycle to 60 minutes. I believe it's 2 hours for Mysql by default.

Comment: 60 seconds. What do you recommend instead? the link I posted says 3600. As I said, no problems so far... can a low timeout cause problems in any way? Also sorry for not noticing you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, I only saw SQLAlchemy=1.3.7

Comment: Using sessions does not help, because a session among other things such as handling the unit of work pattern also necessarily holds on to a connection as long as it has a transaction going on.

Comment: Yes, but you can manage many sessions through a single connection, potentially mitigating the "too many connections" problem.

Comment: Not if they're concurrently in transaction, which usually the issue. Also, given the pooling behaviour you can manage many operations (transactions) using a single connection as well, as long as they're not concurrent.